# Using 3rd Party C files with C Lion, a beginner perspective

Tags: c, clion

I am in despair for a simple explanation to a simple problem.
I made a program in java that I need to recode in C for performance reasons. So I learned how to program in C. The problem is that C standard libraries do not contain collections (why????) such as a hashtables, treesets, etc. So I found this: https://github.com/srdja/Collections-C.

I use CLion on windows, I know well about coding but NOTHING about compiling, CMake, Linux, etc. My question is: I want to use those external source files my project, why is that so hard ? The tutorial on the link provided above tells me to use Linux command lines and stuff that I don't understand. Online I find stuff about telling me to add commands into CMakelist, none of these work for diverse reasons. I can't even copy all the .c and .h into my project because "they are not part of the project". So can anyone tell me how to make this simple code work ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hashtable.h"
int main() {
    Hashtable *table;
    hashtable_new(&table); //this is a function that creates the new hashtable in the source code of Collections-C
    return 0;
}
```

By the way, because I think it's the same problem, how can I have subdirectories in my project so that I can put my header files away to keep the project tree tidy? I tried to add `add_subdirectories($/include)` to my CMakelist.txt

I am expecting people telling me that there are many similar questions already, but none of those I found is clear to me.

Thank you if you have the patience to explain this to me.

Henri

Comment: Part of the reason that the C standard library doesn’t provide containers is that C doesn’t support generic programming (neither Java’s generics nor its near-universal `Object` type).  Another reason is that C is often used to *implement* custom versions of such data structures.

Comment: Yes & not $ I'll modify

Comment: Do you mean that i have to copy - paste the code of the DS I need and change the void pointers to the struct I want them to contain? That for every struct in my program ?

Comment: "*I know well about coding but NOTHING about compiling, CMake, Linux, etc. ...*" so well, the annoying it might sound, you would not get around learning it though: New stuff, new efforts, new pain, new success! ;-)

Comment: As much as I can feel with you, I am voting to close your question as being much to broad.

Comment: @Henri.D: More or less.  Sometimes people use the preprocessor to generate such copies only during compilation.  Or they cast the `void*` to the correct type at each use.  Such ugly code usually appears in only a few places (behind appropriate abstractions), so it’s not as bad as it sounds.  (Also, use @ to reply to comments.)

Comment: there are two steps from source code to executable.  The first is compiling.  When the compiling does not produce any errors/warnings, Then all the resulting object files + needed libraries need to be linked together to produce the executable.

Answer (score 0):

This is for C++, but it should work for your C code. In this example, it's defining where to find the OpenSSL and Google Test headers, and how to link with the Google Test library and the OpenSSL library (which is in C, as it turns out):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(stackexample)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
find_library(GTest required)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS} /usr/include/openssl)

set(
    SOURCE_FILES
    StackExample.cpp
    StackExample.h
)

add_executable(stackexample ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(stackexample -lgtest -lssl -lcrypto pthread)
```

Collections-C appears to have an installer, so you would

- List the path to its installed headers in the `include_directories` line
- List its installed library in the `target_link_libraries` line

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to build the library then do stuff with CMake. I followed [this](https://limeoats.com/clion-and-cmake.html) tutorial.